# How to stream the output into browser using flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, yield

I am new to flask. I have code which streams the output to browser. For my below code, i need to input the range value from browser and display the count till the range. thanks in advance.

```
import flask
import time

from jinja2 import Environment
from jinja2.loaders import FileSystemLoader

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    def inner():
        for x in range(100):# eg: 100 should input value from browser 
            time.sleep(1)
            yield '%s<br/>\n' % x
    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))
    tmpl = env.get_template('result.html')
    return flask.Response(tmpl.generate(result=inner()))

app.run(debug=True)


result.html
<html>
{% block body %}
<body>
  {% for line in result %}
    {{ line }}
  {% endfor %}
</body>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Comment: You want to do it dynamically like user enters the value from the browser and without a page load you show the count?

Comment: thanks Amit, yes that is the requirement. User enters the value and display the output in same page or another page. Whichever is easy.

Comment: If you plan on using Flask Jinja2 without ajax then you have to either reload the page or open a new page. If you use ajax loading content dynamically is possible without page reload.

Comment: yes... without using ajax, what is the change i need to do in above code to access the user input in flask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer to do what you are trying to do.

I have modified your app code to:

```
import flask
import time

from flask import request
from jinja2 import Environment
from jinja2.loaders import FileSystemLoader

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    result = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        counter = int(request.form.get('counter', 0))
        def inner():
            for x in range(counter):# eg: 100 should input value from browser 
                time.sleep(1)
                yield '%s<br/>\n' % x
        result = inner
    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))
    tmpl = env.get_template('result.html')
    return flask.Response(tmpl.generate(result=result if result is None else result()))

app.run(debug=True)
```

Here I have modified the index view to handle both `GET` and `POST` methods. If a simple `GET` requests comes it returns the template with `result=None` and if method is `POST` it `returns=result()`(I have assigned result=inner in POST block). The logic to handle None or a value is handled in the template.

And your template needs to be changed to:

```
<html>
{% block body %}
<body>
{% if result%}
  {% for line in result %}
    {{ line }}
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a number" name="counter">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
{% endif %}
</body>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

I have added the if-else condition as you are using the same template and even the URL doesn't change.

You can follow [Flask Quickstart Tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/) to learn more